# Newsletter Block

Tags: php, html

Just wondering if someone can help me create a newsletter block on my website.

So far I have the following on the site:

```
<div class="one-fourth-last panel border-vert-left newsletter">
                    <div class="padleft">
                    <h4>Join Our<br/> Newsletter</h4>
                    <p>To receieve our newsletter, simply sign up below:</p>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td><input name="" class="field"/></td>
                        <td><input type="image" name="go" src="images/newsletter-input-button.png" alt="Go" class="form-imagebutton" /></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>

                <span class="small">* We will not share your information.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Now I'm using Campaign Monitor for newsletter sign-ups and I somehow need to intergrate the following:

```
<form id="newsletter-form" action="http://companyname.createsend.com/t/r/s/hrihuj/"  method="post">
                    <p>Stay up-to-date with what we're up to</p>            
                    <input id="email-address" type="text" value="Join our newsletter" name="cm-hrihuj-hrihuj"  onclick="this.value='';" />
                    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="go" name="commit"/> 
                    </form>
```

Into what I have already without having to further change the CSS to accomodate this and would appreciate someone showing me how I can intergrate the campaign monitor code into the existing code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
        <div class="one-fourth-last panel border-vert-left newsletter">
            <div class="padleft">
            <h4>Join Our<br/> Newsletter</h4>
            <p>To receieve our newsletter, simply sign up below:</p>

            <form id="newsletter-form" action="http://companyname.createsend.com/t/r/s/hrihuj/"  method="post">
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td><input id="email-address" name="cm-hrihuj-hrihuj" onclick="this.value='';" type="text" class="field" /></td>
                  <td><input type="image" name="commit" src="images/newsletter-input-button.png" alt="Go" class="form-imagebutton" /></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </form>

          <span class="small">* We will not share your information.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm not sure wether you need to update the `action` param within the `<form>` tag.
Maybe you need to do that.

Comment: Hi, that is great thank...I have however, lost the styling for the button on the form...if I repost the CSS also would you see if you can see what I might need to amend? Thanks

Comment: It is as follows: .newsletter .field {
  background:url(../images/newsletter-input-bakground.png) no-repeat; width:146px; height:26px;
  border:0px; font-size:12px; padding-left:10px;
}

Comment: Hi! I think I have tomatoes on my eyes ;-p. I don't know why this behaviour is actually like you described. Their should be no difference... Maybe you try to remove `id="email-address"` from the first `<input>` tag. It's possible that you assigned that id a stylesheet...

Comment: No, still the same...will need to mess with CSS. Thanks for your help, much appreciated